# How to do a surgery on an Eloquent Query on-the-fly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**is there any way to interrupt and change the components and scopes of an eloquent query?**

in order **to add multitenancy** to an existing project, **I've added a global scope** to my models, **filtering results by tenant_id**. and it works fine.

the problem is **I have found more than 500 hardcoded 'where conditions ' and 'create statements'** all over the place. such as these:

```
$notification_type= NotificationTypes::where('id', '2')->get();
```

or

```
$tickets = Tickets::create( $title, $body, $sender, '1'); // 1 as statusID
```

etc.

It's a problem because **I'm using the single DB approach for multitenancy and these IDs must be relative to the tenant**.  for Example in the first query above, I don't want the 'NotificationTypes' with Id of '2', But I want the 'second' NotificationType with that tenant_id (id of this column could be 4 or 7 or else).

I can figure out a way to properly calculate the exact amount of these Relative IDs. but **is there any way to find the prior scope and conditions of an eloquent object and change them?**

I'm looking for a way to add multitenancy to the project without changing much of the existing code. like a module or plugin.

Comment: There's not much you can do. As @Flame said, it's time to roll up the sleeves and refactor this code. Even if you find a solution to this issue, it will only increase the technical debt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope in Laravel

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

Then in your controller just call

```
$notification_type = NotificationTypes::active()->get();
```

More ref on doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes

**Dynamic Scope**

```
public function scopeActive($query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('active', $value);
}

$notification_type = NotificationTypes::active(value_you_want)->get();
```

Change value_you_want with what you want

Or you can use

```
$notification_type = NotificationTypes::where('id', 1)->orWhere('tenant_id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: thanks, correct me if I'm mistaken, but that would require changing all +500 lines of where and create statements. I rather not change much of the existing code.

Comment: I'm already update my answer

Comment: sounds like the original code was written poorly so some refactoring would be welcome. A properly editor should help you out wih those 500 lines though